# Updating property values of JSON object arrays (React JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, loops

I'm trying to map all the "failed subjects and their points" into one array and add a button for each subject that will increase value of points but only for the item clicked.

JSON file:

```
{
    "firstyear": {
        "passed": [{ "name": "English", "points": 0 }, { "name": "History", "points": 0 }],
        "failed": [{ "name": "Chemistry", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Agrictulture", "points": 0 }]
    },
    "secondyear": {
        "passed": [{ "name": "Medicine", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Arts", "points": 0 }],
        "failed": [{ "name": "Gym", "points": 0 }, { "name": "German", "points": 0 }]
    },
    "thirdyear": {
        "passed": [{ "name": "Math", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Informatics", "points": 0 }],
        "failed": [{ "name": "French", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Economics", "points": 0 }]
    },
    "fourthyear": {
        "passed": [{ "name": "Litretarue", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Philosophy", "points": 0 }],
        "failed": [{ "name": "Politics", "points": 0 }, { "name": "Gardening", "points": 0 }]
    }
}
```

Subjects.js:

```
import {fetchAll} from '../AppFetch';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default function Subjects() {

    const [data, setData] = useState({});
      
    useEffect(( ) => {
      fetchAll("http://localhost:3000/example.json", setData)
    }, []);

    const failedArr = [];

    for(let i=0; i<Object.entries(data).length; i++){
      const status = Object.values(data)[i];
  
      for(let j=0; j < Object.keys(status).length; j++){
        const failed=Object.entries(status)[j][1]
        
        failedArr.push(failed[j])
      }
    }
    
    return <div className="row">
      {failedArr.map(key => (
        <div key={key.name}>
          <button>Add point</button>
          <p>{key.name} - {key.points}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>;
}
```

After increasing the values they should be updated in the local JSON file.

Whatever I try isn't working so please help if you can.

Comment: You need to have a backend api that writes to the file, you can't do it with client side React. Create an endpoint that accepts the newly updated state, and then overwrite the JSON file server side.

Comment: thank you for the helpful information!  do you maybe know how can i make this button work for each property of the mapped array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can not be done from frontend. You need a backend server for handling any "write-to-file" task. You can use **Node.js express** or another alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information! Do you maybe know how can I make mapped buttons work, for each item in array?

Comment: Briefly, each child must have a unique key prop while you create an array of React elements. Provide a link to your work (github, sandbox) so I can help you out